# k3 surface as ramified double cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I read that one example of k3 surface is a double cover of $\mathbb{P}^2\mathbb{C}$ ramified over a sextic. My question is why a sextic? i believe that the sextic is isomorphic to the ramification divisor, but why is this? also how can i see that k3 surfaces realized this way are deformation equivalent? 
thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Q1:** Hurwitz formula + canonical divisor of $\mathbb P^2$.

**Q2:** Move the curve in $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Upvoted for terseness.

Comment: Downvoted for terseness.

Comment: Seriously, @Garfield? You wouldn't put your real name to your actions, but you make sophisticated judgement calls. This answer teaches *rick* (and *you*) to fish instead of giving him (and you) something to eat. The part that's not included in this answer belongs to *http://math.stackexchange.com/*. Not that I care for those puny points, but I am deeply disappointed in trying to help people who want pre-chewed food instead of learning how to hunt. 

Comment: ps: if there is a point you don't understand or get stuck with, then ask a specific (follow up) question...

Comment: i'm sorry, i didn't mean to disappoint you, i asked just because i had no idea how to solve it. By the Hurwitz formula ($\pi$ is the double cover) i get $K_X\simeq \pi^*(K_{\mathbb{P}^2})\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(\sum_i(e_i-1)C_i)$, so, since $K_{\mathbb{P}^2}=-3[H]$, it must be $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(\sum_i(e_i-1)C_i)=6[H]$, i.e. it is a sextic, am i right?

Comment: @rick, that comment was addressed to *Garfield*, not you. This is a perfectly fine question. And yes, your computation is right. That was the point of my comment: I believed that if I tell you to use the Hurwitz formula then you can figure it out yourself. It seems I was right and I think you might appreciate it more this way that you did part of the work. So, please do not take that comment to heart, it wasn't meant for you. Cheers!

Comment: ps: Strictly speaking one should add that your formula works, because it is a double cover, but I am sure you thought of that and at least on this page I cannot criticize anyone for terseness. :)

Comment: I am sorry if this painted the wrong picture, but there is really no need to get offended. Opinions differ, and to continue your metaphor, I believe that people who come here have already tried to fish for months, are starving for food, and they should receive it. A complete answer on mathoverflow isn't spoonfeeding, it's what the site is made for. The site *wants* me to downvote when I don't find an answer helpful, and I did. I even left a comment to explain. Please understand that while experienced people might find terseness helpful, less experienced people might not.

Comment: 
Dear *Garfield*: First of all, I am not offended at all. Nothing happened that would
warrant that. I said I was disappointed and that is what I am. I understand that you
probably felt frustrated, but I don't think you approached the issue the right
way. In case it hasn't been clear, my problem is not with your downvote, but with
your comment and even more the attitude that it suggests.


Comment: This site works because people volunteer their time and energy to answer
questions. Your smug and demanding attitude does not help that. When I wrote the
original answer I didn't have time to write more and I thought this is still better
than nothing. It gives a hint that might help the OP to work out the answer. It turns
out that it was indeed enough for him. I initially thought I might come back and add
more details, but then the two comments about terseness appeared....

Comment:  After your comment
I **could not** in good conscience add details, because then it would have looked
like I am doing it to avoid further downvotes. So, you see, your comment actually
backfired.


Comment: Your statement about the site wanting you to vote this answer down is a bit of a stretch, but fine, I accept it. However, if you are so keen on doing what the site wants, then why don't you do it? Look up *Where's the rule that says I have to wear pants?* in the FAQ. It discusses voting down, but even more importantly it encourages you to use your real name.

Comment: Mr. Kovács, you're the one who's being smug. Also, I am not frustrated, I simply put a downvote on an answer which I thought wasn't helpful. My comment stated the dry fact that terseness is not a positive attribute when it comes to math. That has nothing to do with attitude, much opposed to your childish lamenting. What's that about not adding details *because* I suggested it'd be helpful? Because you were afraid of getting further downvotes? Seriously man, grow up.

Comment: @Garfield: my problem was exactly that you did not suggest that adding details would be helpful. Regarding being afraid about downvotes, read my comment again. Finally, how about continuing this discussion like grown ups who are not afraid to reveal their identity?

Comment: @Garfield: what is more childish? Answering people's questions or pretending to be a fat lazy cartoon cat....
